# WordPress can't edit page on other computers

Tags: wordpress, edit

I can edit all pages on the computer of server. Here is the picture. It looks all good.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwHxj.png)

But when I used another computer to edit, the page can not display the contents that I edited before. It displayed nothing. It can't even edit anymore. Here is the picture. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvykv.png)

But I can see the contents I edited before when I connect to the web.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1lWw.png)

On other computers, I can't type word, can't add link, and the options can't work neither.
I have already deactivated all plugins. And I tried cleaning the cache of the browser. But they don't work. Is there any suggestion to help me solve this problem? Thank you.

After I looked into the develop console, here are some errors. But I don't know what they means. I am trying to google them to figure out what happens. Here is the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guOrt.png)

Comment: From this images we can't suggest anything.
Look into developer console into Chrome. Maybe you can see there something reliable.

Comment: @PavloZhukov Thanks for your suggetion. Here are some uncaught errors.  I am trying to google to figure out what happens. I don't know how to put images in comments so I put the image in the article.

Comment: You can update your question and put image there

Comment: @PavloZhukov Thanks. I edited the question and put the image already.

Comment: For some reason you don't have **jQuery** which is used in most of Wordpress JS code. Try to figure out what's wrong with this in your code

Comment: @PavloZhukov OK. I google the problem and find some methods in this website (https://wpcolt.com/jquery-not-defined-possible-causes-fix-wordpress/)  I tried the method 1, and it works. I can edit pages from other computer now, but the errors in console still exist.

Comment: I think some process broke you JS scripts. It could be used webserver or its module. You need to investigate it in your environment. When you resolve it, jQuery also need to works fine

Comment: We don't do "solved" in the title here. If you found an answer, either post it below and accept it, or delete the question. Thanks.

Comment: @PavloZhukov OK, but I have no idea what the problem is and how to fix it. I will try to understand it . Really thank you for helping me!

Comment: @j08691 Sorry for the mistake. I will fix it. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the method1 in the website below.
[here is the link](https://wpcolt.com/jquery-not-defined-possible-causes-fix-wordpress/)

And it works. I can edit pages from other computer right now. But the errors in the developer console in Chrome still exist.